# Fatal error encountered during command execution.'

Tags: vb.net

I want to save the rows of datagridview into the database. I am using editbtn click button, when I press the button it gives me the following error: "**Fatal error encountered during command execution**." Here is the code which I am using

```
Private Sub Supplier_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=pembelian;Uid=root;Pwd=;"
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
        conn.Open()
        disp_data()
    End Sub
Public Sub disp_data()
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from supplier"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
 
Private Sub edit_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles edit_btn.Click
        Dim query As String = "updates supplier set nama=@nama, alamat=@alamat where npwp=@npwp"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", nama.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat", alamat.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil di update")
        disp_data()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean VBA like your tag suggest? It looks like VB.Net to me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's *not good* to re-use the same connection object throughout your application. There is a feature in ADO.Net called **connection pooling**, where the `MySqlConnection` object you use in your code is actually a simple wrapper for the real underlying connection. These real connections are much heavier and more expensive to manage. They handle the real work of authentication, getting network socket resources, negotiating with the server, etc.

When you try to re-use the same connection object, you are optimizing the small thing (`MySqlConnection`) at the expense of the big thing (the real underlying connections). Don't do that.

Instead, you really are much better off creating a new connection for most queries, and then returning it to the pool as quickly as possible. This is normally handled with a `Using` block.

---

That out of the way I can look at the actual question. I noticed the `@npwp` parameter is not defined in the last method. Guessing at the name of the appropriate field, you want something more like this:

```
Private Sub edit_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles edit_btn.Click
    Dim query As String = "updates supplier set nama=@nama, alamat=@alamat where npwp=@npwp"
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=pembelian;Uid=root;Pwd=;")
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", nama.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat", alamat.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@npwp", npwp.Text)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil di update")
    disp_data()
End Sub

Public Sub disp_data()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Dim query As String = "select * from supplier"
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=pembelian;Uid=root;Pwd=;")
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    Using da As New MySqlDataAdapater(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    End Using
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Still cannot it got an error message  System.InvalidOperationException: **Connection must be valid and open.**

Comment: @MasaDepan Forgot the .Open() call, fixed now. Added `disp_data()`, too.

Comment: I see you use a DataAdpater to fill the DataTable. I have been using a DataRaeader which I believe would be used internally by the adpater. Is there a preference to use the adapter rather than a reader? I would have thought the reader was a bit lighter because of extra functionality of the adapter.

Comment: @Mary My normal inclination is a datareader here as well, but I stuck with the DataAdapter in this case to match the original question more closely.